# Finding the Hilbert expansion of a D4 Coulomb branch

Tags: string-theory, gauge-theory, branes

I am trying to compute the HS of the following Coulomb branch, but first I am not sure how to proceed in interpreting the diagram and what variables to use. I am trying to use the equation from this paper [Monopole operators and Hilbert series of Coulomb branches of 3d ${\cal N} = 4$ gauge theories](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.2657).
Any help or hint will be appreciated.

[image: ![D4 coulomb branch]

Comment: That would be the gauge theory from part 3.4 of the paper? And the Young tableau is explained in Appendix A?

Comment: @MitchellPorter In order to obtain the Young tables the values of the magnetic flux are needed, so what are they for this diagram?

Comment: Do you need to know specific values? Or just multiplicities? - "how many of the fluxes... are equal"